# Creating a Google Script to copy values from a table to a different table on a seperate tab for Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to create a script that allows you to copy the value of one table (that have a variety of formulae in it) into a different table automatically on Sunday nights.

You can find sheet I'm making [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mi5aTK_tOX7x9d0aLQI7Wgy0MOaD-EMRl7UGNnrihus/edit?usp=sharing). The content of sheet1's table is what I want copied over to the table in sheet 3, under 'stock tea'.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so what? Asking since this is not a coding service.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet unfortuantly. I've asked before on here for coding help but nothing from scratch, so sorry for that! I can delete the post if it's not allowed.

Comment: Start by looking at what is possible to do using google apps scripts. It's based on Javascript so there's plenty of documentation around to get started (plus becomes super useful going forward). Start here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials and then check out the specific methods you need for your task, e.g. here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed. Then when you run into trouble you can ask more specific questions here and get help on them

Comment: So I've made a basic script:

`function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet3')
sheet.getRange("C4:F22").copyTo(sheet2.getRange("C5"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
  
}`
but it copies and pastes the whole formulea and conditinal formating, even when I specify `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES`

Comment: That's a great start even if the behaviour is strange, maybe try https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend instead?

Comment: you need to pass third argument as a boolean value "false" (which is for transpose) in the method copyTo

Comment: So, this works for me,
`function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet3');

var trgtRange = sheet2.getRange('C5:F23')

var values = sheet.getRange("C4:F22").getValues();

trgtRange.setValues(values);

}`

Thank you so much for pointing me in the right directions!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet3');
  var range = sheet1.getRange("C4:F22");
  var values = range.getValues();
  range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange("C5"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```